# Configure Interception with Unity AutoConfig in VB.NET

Tags: c#-to-vb.net, unity-interception

I'm trying to get interception working in vb.net since my work only allows that. The way I would use it is to configure say some logger so that every business logic function that gets run is intercepted and logged to the database (bad idea, but its just an example). This is an example that I found:

```
    container
    .ConfigureAutoRegistration()
    .Include(If.Implements<IBusinessService>, (x, y) =>
    {
        if (x.IsClass)
            y.Configure<Interception>().
                SetDefaultInterceptorFor(x,new VirtualMethodInterceptor());
    })
```

This is what I tried to get working in vb.net, but it keeps throwing an error.

```
    container.
    ConfigureAutoRegistration().
    Include([if].ImplementsITypeName, Function(x, y)
        if x.IsClass
            y.Configure(of Interception)()
                .SetDefaultInterceptorFor(x,new VirtualMethodInterceptor())
    End Function)
```

The error is:

```
Argument not specified for parameter 'type' of 'Public Shared Function ImplementsITypeName(type as System.Type) As Boolean.
```

Now obviously I need to specify some type, but the point is that I need to autoregister, so why do I need to provide a type? Also, the C# code doesn't require it, and neither does the code sample (see below).

```
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container
            .ConfigureAutoRegistration()
            .ExcludeAssemblies(a => a.GetName().FullName.Contains("Test"))
            .Include(If.Implements<ILogger>, Then.Register().UsingPerCallMode())
            .Include(If.ImplementsITypeName, Then.Register().WithTypeName())
            .Include(If.Implements<ICustomerRepository>, Then.Register().WithName("Sample"))
            .Include(If.Implements<IOrderRepository>,
                     Then.Register().AsSingleInterfaceOfType().UsingPerCallMode())
            .Include(If.DecoratedWith<LoggerAttribute>,
                     Then.Register()
                            .As<IDisposable>()
                            .WithTypeName()
                            .UsingLifetime<MyLifetimeManager>())
            .Exclude(t => t.Name.Contains("Trace"))
            .ApplyAutoRegistration();
```

http://autoregistration.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using structure map.